# ListView not update

Tags: listview, flutter, widget

The void gerarLista input some values in var List listaNumeros. For some reason when the list is written the screen is not updated.

When I'm on the go live and change something in the code and save the list is redesigned bringing the information.

````
var sequencia = [];
var numeroInicialController = TextEditingController();
var dddController = TextEditingController();
var quantidadeController = TextEditingController();

void gerarLista(int numeroInicial, int ddd, int quantidade) {
  print(numeroInicial.toString());
  print(ddd.toString());
  print(quantidade.toString());

  for (var i = numeroInicial; i <= (numeroInicial + quantidade); i++) {
    sequencia.add(i);
  }

  var cod = 1;
  //listaNumeros.clear();
  for (var numero in sequencia) {
    listaNumeros.add(Numero(numero.toString(), ddd.toString(), cod.toString()));
    cod++;
  }
  print(sequencia);
}

class _MessengerApp extends State<MessengerApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //var listaNumeros = new List<int>.generate(quantidade, (numeroInicial) => numeroInicial + 1);

    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('JW Messenger'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  _showDialog();
                },
                child: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
              )),
        ],
      ),
      body: (ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ...listaNumeros,
        ],
      )),
    ));
  }```
````

Comment: Where is your `listaNumeros` declared and where are you calling the function `gerarLista` in you code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide more code so we can understand what's going on, for now I can't see where you are calling `setState()`.

You need to call `setState()` in order to trigger a rebuild in Flutter.

Also, it's common to have a list that doesn't update on screen, when that happens you need to use Keys, take a look at Keys in Flutter and how they are used to identify new and updated widgets for the framework.

Comment: Truth. I put SetState and updated the interface. Thank you!